# Spark Scala: How to filter RDD and update counter at the same time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark/scala. My initial RDD is of type Records and the layout of the records is :

```
a_key, b_key,c_key,f_name,l_name,address
```

Now I have to :

- drop the records that has either of the a_key or b_key or c_key is null/empty
- I have to update a counter for the invalid records at the same time.

I have tried it this way :

```
sc.register( recordStatsAccumulator, "Stat accumulator for " + filename )

val nullFilteredRecords = records.map{ record =>

  if( record.A_KEY.isEmpty ||
    record.B_KEY.isEmpty ||
    record.C_KEY.isEmpty )
  {
    recordStatsAccumulator.add( ValidationLoggingUtil.INVALID )
  }

  record

 }
 .filter( record =>
    !record.A_KEY.isEmpty &&
      !record.B_KEY.isEmpty &&
      !record.C_KEY.isEmpty
  )
```

However, this code is not efficient as it goes thorugh  the whole RDD twice. First, to update a counter for invalid records and then again to drop the invalid records.

Is there better/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can union the two operations in one step. Like this:

```
val nullFilteredRecords = records.filter { record =>
  if( record.A_KEY.isEmpty ||
    record.B_KEY.isEmpty ||
    record.C_KEY.isEmpty ) {
    recordStatsAccumulator.add( ValidationLoggingUtil.INVALID )
  }
  !record.A_KEY.isEmpty && !record.B_KEY.isEmpty && !record.C_KEY.isEmpty
}
```